# Adjust vertical aligment of text for rowspan cells upon hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an interesting problem here:

There is a table with a handful of cells, some of them have rowspans:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    | c4 | cx |
|    | c2 +----+----+
|    |    | c5 | cx |
| c1 +----+----+----+
|    |    | c6 | cx |
|    | c3 +----+----+
|    |    | c7 | cx |
+----+----+---------+
```

When I hover over a row lets say the first row, I want to display it something like this

```
+----+----+----+----+
| c1 | c2 | c4 | cx |
|    |    +----+----+
|    |    | c5 | cx |
|    +----+----+----+
|    |    | c6 | cx |
|    | c3 +----+----+
|    |    | c7 | cx |
+----+----+---------+
```

So basically the values of the rowspan cells appear on the same row as the highlighted row.

Here is a jsfiddle with the highlighting working:
https://jsfiddle.net/ucarL9e9/1/

So whenever I highlight a row I want to temporary change the vertical alignment of the cell to make it with the row that highlighted. So something like this:

[image: Image2]

I'm not worried about the color just the value of the cell

Comment: "Hovering". Hoovering is what the English do when their floors are dusty.

Comment: But aren't the values already present? And what HTML are you working with? What CSS, or JavaScript, have you tried already? What went wrong, how did it fail?

Comment: As you can see, your question is about to be closed. I suggest you have a look at the help docs, where you'll learn that it's important to make an effort and ask a specific question on SO. "Any ideas" is usually a red flag.

Comment: Show the relevant code.. atleast..

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://techbrij.com/html-table-row-grouping-jquery) (and its reverse) would work.

Comment: Here is something to get you started with. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbb3f8yf/) . I am sure that there are different approaches to what you are looking for. This is just one idea.

Comment: Thank you bro!!! your awesome. Just need something to get started.

Comment: gets buggy when there is two or more rowspan check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jbb3f8yf/3/